# How can I get access to my docker containers environment variables in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I am trying to get access to some docker environment variables in my C# code running on .Net Core.

In my dockerfile generated by VS, I added environment variables like this:

```
ENV EnvKey = "value"
```

After building this image and starting the instance with the built-in Docker startup option in VS, I inspect my docker image with `docker inspect MyInstance`.

The resulting output lists my previously defined environment variable in "Config" -> "Env" -> "EnvKey", so I'm sure it is there.

For some testing, I try to access them with the following code:

```
var keys = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
```

However, this does not retrieve the environment variable that is contained in the container.

What else do I need to configure to get this working?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Yes, Asp.Net Core 3.1

Comment: how do you understand that `keys` does not contain your `EnvKey`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was very simple actually - In my case, this wasn't visible from the question.

But my real environment variable key had some "." in it. I replaced those with "_" and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an ASP.NET application, then updating the Dockerfile to `ENV ASPNETCORE_EnvKey = "value"` should do the trick for you.

If you are running some other .NET core app on your machine, then look at the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8#on-macos-and-linux-systems). It would seem you can't do this on the machine level, but in your `RUN` command, you would have to pass the 'environment variables' to the process through the dotnet command you are invoking there.

Comment: Didn't check your second part yet, but the first part of the answer is not quite working sadly. I read up about this being mandatory for the ASPNETCORE_Environment parameter, but nothing else